How can I log from inside an extension method?
I have error classes that are used in business services. Discriminated union OneOf<> is used to allow the service method return one result from multiple possible results.
// Errors
public record Error(string Code, string Description);
public sealed record NotDeleted(int Id, string EntityName) : Error("NotDeleted",
        $"{EntityName} with Id = {Id} cannot be deleted.");
public sealed record NotFound(int Id, string EntityName) : Error("NotFound",
        $"{EntityName} with Id = {Id} cannot be found.");

// Business Services
public sealed class MovieService(AppDbContext db)
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _db = db;
    public async Task<OneOf<NotFound, NotDeleted, Movie>> DeleteMovieAsync(int id, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var movie = await _db.Movies
                .Include(m => m.Genres)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id, ct);

        if (movie is null)
            return new NotFound(id, nameof(Movie));

        _db.Movies.Remove(movie);

        return await _db.SaveChangesAsync(ct) > 0
            ? movie
            : new NotDeleted(id, nameof(Movie));
    }
}

The business services are injected into endpoints.
// Endpoints
public static class MovieEndpoints
{
    public static void MapMovieEndpoints(this IEndpointRouteBuilder app)
    {
        var group = app.MapGroup("api/movies");
        group.MapDelete("{id}", DeleteMovieAsync);
    }
    private static async Task<Results<ProblemHttpResult, Ok<MovieResponse>>>
        DeleteMovieAsync(int id, MovieService ms, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var result = await ms.DeleteMovieAsync(id, ct);

        return result.Match<Results<ProblemHttpResult, Ok<MovieResponse>>>(
           notFoundError => notFoundError.ToProblemDetails(),
           notDeletedError => notDeletedError.ToProblemDetails(),
           movie => TypedResults.Ok(movie.MapToMovieResponse()));
    }
}

I extend Error class to produce ProblemDetails as follows.
How can I log inside ToProblemDetails() (indicated with // Logging goes here!)?
// Mappers
public static class ErrorMapper
{
    private static ProblemHttpResult ToProblemDetails(Error error, int statusCode)
    {
        // Logging goes here!
        return TypedResults.Problem(new ProblemDetails
        {
            Title = error.Code,
            Detail = error.Description,
            Status = statusCode
        });
    }
    public static ProblemHttpResult ToProblemDetails(this NotFound error)
        => ToProblemDetails(error, StatusCodes.Status404NotFound);

    public static ProblemHttpResult ToProblemDetails(NotDeleted error)
        => ToProblemDetails(error, StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
}


You would need to a) pass the logger instance as a parameter, or b) add a static logger to the ErrorMapper class.
But in reality that is not a good place to log the error. Static methods can't be mocked and logging isn't really the purpose of that function.
You should be logging in the controller. Something like:
    private static async Task<Results<ProblemHttpResult, Ok<MovieResponse>>>
        DeleteMovieAsync(int id, MovieService ms, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var result = await ms.DeleteMovieAsync(id, ct);

        var response = result.Match<Results<ProblemHttpResult, Ok<MovieResponse>>>(
           notFoundError => notFoundError.ToProblemDetails(),
           notDeletedError => notDeletedError.ToProblemDetails(),
           movie => TypedResults.Ok(movie.MapToMovieResponse()));

         if (response is Error) {
             _logger.Error(response);
         }

         return response;
    }


How about logging in the business service MovieService? Because it is the nearest source of problem, right?

That's fine. The service should have access to dependency injection if you're using it for the logger and service. Whether to log at high level or in business layer is a philosophical question really.
Another option is to throw the error from the business service instead of returning it and then handling and logging it in the controller. The stack trace will show the source. This will also simplify your logic so you don't need to return OneOf<>, you would just have a single return type. But again, that's a philosophical decision.

OK. I am using discriminated union to avoid throwing known exceptions. Thank you.
